# Can I create map <string,map<string, int[2]> >?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, pipe

My problem is that I need to create this map structure so I can store two normal strings and an int array of two pipes fd.

The code I have is:

```
map<string, map <string, int[2]> > fillEndPipes(Automata a){

map <string, map<string, int[2]> > tempMap;

vector <string> tempVector = a.getStates();
vector <string>::const_iterator it;
string name = a.getName();

for(it = tempVector.begin(); it != tempVector.end(); it++){
    int tuberia[2];
    pipe (tuberia);


    map<string, int[2]> innerMap;
    innerMap.insert(pair<string,int>((*it),(tuberia)));

    tempMap.insert(pair<string, map <string, int[2]> >(name,innerMap));


}

    return tempMap;
}
```

The thing I haven't found a way to insert the int[2] to the pair or map.

Comment: It won't work. But you can use an `std::array<int, 2>` instead of the plain array.

Comment: That will complicate things for you. Why don't you just create a class with everything you want and store the pointers in the map/vector ?

Comment: Use typedef to avoid code repetition. It will also help you to modify data structure later much easier if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a struct & use it in place of `int[2]`

```
struct pipefd {
    int fdin;
    int fdout;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::pair

```
 map <string, map<string, pair<int,int> > > tempMap;
```